# How to add page into Navigation stack?( Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

when I navigate to Page1.xaml, I have an empty navidation stack, what I need to add into

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e){}
```

to add Page2.xaml into Navigation stack (I need to navidate into Page2.xaml only when I press go back button)

Comment: I think this would be confusing. Why would you want to do it?

Comment: do you know how to implement this?

Comment: No but the non linear navigation service might help http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/nln-serv-wp7

Comment: Certification requirements state that pressing the back button on the first screen must close the application.  It also says that Pressing the Back button must return the application to the previous page or return to any previous page within the back stack.  So adding a page into the back stack will almost certainly cause it to fail certification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to navigate to Page2.xaml when the user press the Back button, correct?

You'll have to use the BackKeyPressed event to make that work, like so:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.BackKeyPress += new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs>(MainPage_BackKeyPress);
}

void MainPage_BackKeyPress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    });
}
```

But please be advised that changing the default behavior of the Back button may lead to fail app certification!